# Moderator election: who should nominate themselves?

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

As anybody can see, (nomination for) moderator election is running, but there are only 2 candidates so far. And (with all due respect) it doesn't look too... great, so far. Only self-nominations are allowed, but **who, do you think, we should ask to nominate themselves?**

Now, our current moderators do a great job, and it sets standards pretty high, I think.

/* Ideally, moderator should be quite an expert in math, and very active on math.SE, and active in meta-discussions (but always calm and... adequate), and, preferably, having a moderator experience... But it's just theories, so feel free to ignore it. */

And to make it a sorted list, one user per answer, please.

Comment: I think that whoever wants to be moderator should nominate themselves, and that we should save the voting for the actual election.

Comment: @Jonas But maybe we can persuade^W motivate some great people [that wouldn't do otherwise] to nominate themselves? And there is no harm in trying (or is there?).

Answer (score 13):

I don't think we need to ask someone to nominate themselves. Any one who thinks (s)he can be a moderator of this site can nominate themselves. The community will finally decide.

Some of the most important qualities for being a moderator are:

$1$. Must regularly visit the site

$2$. Participate actively on the site and also on meta

$3$. Should take a stance on whether homework problems are allowed or not or what sort of problems are allowed (This homework issue has been going on for a long time)

$4$. Must use their power with discretion

$5$. Keep the community updated with the new rules and new changes to the site

So far Qiaochu Yuan and Willie Wong have done an excellent job in moderating this site. The new moderator should be able to work with them in carrying forward this wonderful site.

Comment: Aren't the new moderators replacing the old moderators?

Comment: @Qiaochu: Not according to http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2307/2011-community-moderator-election

Comment: Oh. Then I don't really think there's a need to ask people to nominate themselves.